# I want to read back a line from a specific line/string in python

Tags: python

this is the code that has me really confused:

```
if search in open('test.txt').read():
    print("product is found")
```

i am trying to re-read a line fro my text file using the .read() function however i do not know how this would work from searching a single string. EG: if search is 12345 i want to find this in the text file and then output it on the shell. I have tried numerous different ways but cannot get it to work. This is for my work experience and would help me a lot.

Comment: your script should work, but it might be better to open the file line by line and use the `with` statement to handle file closing, e.b. `with open('test.txt') as f:` and `for line in f:` and `if search in line:`

Comment: You can also do : files = open('test.txt').readlines() it will return a list to iterate .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right, you want to get the line which matches the `search`. If so, you just need to read file line by line which can be done like this

```
for line in open('test.txt'):
    if search in line:
        print("Product is found on line", line.strip())
```

Comment: You never close the file

Comment: Chris_Rands, Python will close the file at the end of the script, so for one time script it doesn't seem like a problem.